# Windows 10 clock skips an hour ahead from local time upon reboot

Tags: windows-10, time

My Windows 10 system has a peculiar issue. Despite `Set the time automatically` and `Set the time zone automatically` being enabled in Settings and `time.windows.com` set as the server it will always jump to an hour exactly ahead of local time after a reboot.

The time shows up perfectly fine in the BIOS/UEFI and the date and minutes are fine in Windows.

Clicking the `Sync now` button under `Time & Language` in Settings will always correct this until the next reboot.

Hopefully you might have a similar experience and some advice to what might be the cause.

Comment: Mind sharing your time zone? Also, do you have the "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically" setting enabled?

Comment: Also, is your computer a member of a domain? It is very possible that if this is the case, the domain controller pushes its own incorrect time to combat login issues.

Comment: If it's a dualboot system (e. g. Windows & Linux), this could cause the problem. A solution for dual-boot time corrections can be found here, it would be possible to configure Linux as well as Windows to get the correct time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I do have "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically" enabled. I'm in the U.K. so UTC +1 at the moment. No domain - actually a fresh install although the problem existed on a previous install as well.

Comment: @xph that was it! I can't believe I have never come across this issue before. I have fixed with the RealTimeIsUniversal registry edit which I found online.

Comment: @Jacob: Glad it helped :)  I had the same problem. I would never have guessed dualboot causes the problem, until i found the solution.